# How to have static error when importing undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want a static error when I import something that was not exported.

Like:

## somefile.js

```
import {
  FrontScreen,
  FlowScreen
} from './containers';
```

## containers.js

```
export FrontScreen from './FrontScreen’;
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Maybe some linter rule?

Comment: Do your unit tests not catch this?

Comment: unit tests is a different matter, they are dynamic, I think this could be statically analized

Comment: Not sure if eslint analyzes dependencies, but it might be worth looking into creating a plugin for it.

Comment: Are you using a particular transpiler?

Comment: Actually [this *should* throw a `SyntaxError`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-moduledeclarationinstantiation) when you are importing a name that was not exported. I guess your transpiler is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done by the parser, in your case babel.
Babel will very likely throw a SyntaxError in this situation starting on v6 (judging from a conversation on their slack team), but v5 won't.

They have [an open issue for this](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2599).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do such a thing, and I would actually doubt it's possible in a generic manner, since the object can be dynamically created. Consider:

```
// module.js
function foo() { /* return something .. could be an object, a string, anything */ }
export default foo();
```

Comment: This is not about objects. Export bindings are static.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? The code I posted there is a valid module, correct? If so, then statically, there's no way to tell what properties you can extract from an import.

Comment: It is statically determined that you have a default export and no named ones. We can check that you only `import xy from 'module';` and not something else like `import {notExisting} from 'module';`. We don't know (and don't care) what exact values are exported of course.